# Drag and Resize component -> get the changed style values?

Tags: css, primefaces, styles

I have a question:

I have an component with e.g. <
p:outputPanel style="width: 100px; height: 300; top; 20px; left: 30px"

=> Now I drag and resize the component. Now the style="width: 300px; height: 500; top; 420px; left: 230px"

How can I pass this changed style to my bean? I get only the init value: style="width: 100px; height: 300; top; 20px; left: 30px"

Answer (score 0):

You can take the advantage of jQuery here. It is possible to read an attribute by jQuery:

```
$(".MyUniqueClassName").attr("style");
```

Now you can use a hidden TextInput and a hidden CommandButton to transfer the value to the server.

```
function post(){
    $(".MyTextInput").val($(".MyUniqueClassName").attr("style"));
    $(".MyButton").click();
}
```

Now what you are going to do is call the post() method when you finish resizing or draging your component.